# How to exclude an individual resource from AWS Config

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-config

How can we exclude a specific resource from AWS Config Recorder. I don't want to have to include every resource type this will be a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be helpful. This solution deploys into your AWS Control Tower management account’s home region.  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/customize-aws-config-resource-tracking-in-aws-control-tower-environment/